# How to send email without using SMTP protocol on website in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating contact us page in my website which is in CodeIgniter. I want to send this contact form data in my mail address.

How to send email in CodeIgniter without using SMTP for website?

Comment: ohh yes , use `php mail function`

Answer (score 2):

yes you can use codeIgniter simple mail function.

> Example:-

```
  public function send_mail() { 
         $from_email = "your@example.com"; 
         $to_email = $this->input->post('email'); 

         //Load email library 
         $this->load->library('email'); 

         $this->email->from($from_email, 'Your Name'); 
         $this->email->to($to_email);
         $this->email->subject('Email Test'); 
         $this->email->message('Testing the email class.'); 

         //Send mail 
         if($this->email->send()) 
         $this->session->set_flashdata("email_sent","Email sent successfully."); 
         else 
         $this->session->set_flashdata("email_sent","Error in sending Email."); 
         $this->load->view('email_form'); 
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send a email.
Controller.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Inquiry extends CI_Controller
{
    public function inquiry()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        /* Model */
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('header', array("title" => "Inquiry"));
        $this->load->view('your_view',$view);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }

    function inviteStaff()
    {
        $this->load->library('email');
        $from_email = $_POST['email'];
        $to_email = "your@email.com";
        $body='이름 : '.$_POST['name'].'<br /><br />email : '.$_POST['email'].'<br /><br />contents : '.$_POST['contents'].'';

        $this->email->from($from_email, $_POST['name']);
        $this->email->to($to_email);
        $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
        $this->email->subject('TITLE');
        $this->email->message($body);
        $this->email->send();
    }

    function emailCheck()
    {
        $user_id = base64_decode($_POST['user_id']);
        $email = $_POST['check_mail'];
        $where = array('user_emailId' => $email,'user_id!=' => $user_id);
        $view = $this->mdl_file->sel_where('user_details',$where);
        echo count($view);
    }
}
```

view.

```html
<form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url();?>Inquiry/inviteStaff">
  <div class="item form-group" id="email_div">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 right" for="name">이름<span class="required">*</span>
  </label>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" >
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" placeholder="이름" onblur="return emailCheck();" value="<?php echo @$staff_details[0]['user_emailId'] ?>">
  </div>
  <div class="alert">Your Name.</div>
    <div class="alert_1" style="position: absolute;margin-left: 735px;width: 160px;display: none;margin-top: 5px;color: red;">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item form-group" id="email_div">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 right" for="email">E-mail<span class="required">*</span></label>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" >
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" placeholder="Email" onblur="return emailCheck();" value="<?php echo @$staff_details[0]['user_emailId'] ?>">
  </div>
  <div class="alert">Your Email.</div>
    <div class="alert_1" style="position: absolute;margin-left: 735px;width: 160px;display: none;margin-top: 5px;color: red;">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item form-group" id="email_div">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 right" for="contents">내용<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" >
      <textarea id="contents" name="contents" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" placeholder="내용" onblur="return emailCheck();" value="<?php echo @$staff_details[0]['user_emailId'] ?>" style="height:200px">
      </textarea>
 </div>
 <div class="alert">Contents.</div>
   <div class="alert_1" style="position: absolute;margin-left: 735px;width: 160px;display: none;margin-top: 5px;color: red;">
      </div>
 </div>
</form>
```